# Resolving the type of `f = f (<*>) pure`

Tags: haskell, types, typechecking, applicative

Recently I noticed that humourously `liftA` can be written as

```
liftA (<*>) pure
```

I thought this was neat and so as a bit of a joke I thought I would make a new "definition" of `liftA` based on this property:

```
f = f (<*>) pure
```

Now I had expected that this would be something of the same type as `liftA` that just never halted.  However it fails to compile.

```
• Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
    t ~ (f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b) -> (a1 -> f1 a1) -> t
• In the expression: f (<*>) pure
  In an equation for ‘f’: f = f (<*>) pure
• Relevant bindings include
    f :: (f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b) -> (a1 -> f1 a1) -> t
      (bound at liftA.hs:2:1)
```

This seems sensible, I see how the compiler has an issue.  However things get a little weird because when I add an annotation:

```
f :: Applicative f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
f = f (<*>) pure
```

It suddenly compiles.

Now my initial suspicion was that the type I was annotating `f` with was not the most general type and that by restricting the type I had made it possible to unify things.  However looking at the types this doesn't seem to be the case my type seems to be more general than the type that the compiler was trying to derive.

What is going on here?  I am a bit out of my depth here but I am curious as to what the compiler is thinking in each scenario and why it encounters an issue in one but not the other.

Comment: Your type annotation is not more general, because it restricts `<*>` and `pure` to work in the same Applicative, and with the same `a`. The more general type GHC derived allows for two different Applicatives. So you were right to suspect that by adding a (less general) signature you allowed a non-infinite type to be inferred.

Answer (score 4):

The confusion is caused by Haskell's type classes and the fact that functions-from-fixed-type are an instance of `Applicative` (aka the reader monad). It becomes clearer if you write it out with specialised version:

```
type Reader a b = a -> b

fmapFn :: (a -> b) -> Reader c a -> Reader c b
fmapFn = fmap
    -- ≡ liftA
    -- ≡ (.)

fmap' :: Applicative f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
fmap' = fmapFn (<*>) pure
      ≡ (<*>) . pure
      ≡ \φ -> (<*>) (pure φ)
      ≡ \φ fa -> pure φ <*> fa
```

And at this point it requires the applicative law

```
fmap f x = pure f <*> x
```

so

```
 fmap' ≡ \φ fa -> fmap φ fa
       ≡ fmap
```

*duh*. But the point is, in the definition `fmap' = fmap' (<*>) pure`, the `(<*>)` and `pure` belong to the functor for which you want this to eventually work, but the `fmap'` you're *using* actually always belongs to the function functor. That's ok in Haskell: the definition *is* polymorphic after all, so if the top-level knows how to do this for *all* functors then you can certainly also use it for the function functor. (Leaving aside the issue of nontermination due to circular dependency...)
However, because you're defining it in the form `fmap' = ...`, <del>the [monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction) kicks in: if you write  `fmap' = fmap' (<*>) pure` without signature at the top-level,</del> the compiler tries to find a concrete type for which this should work, in particular a single, concrete functor. But whatever concrete type you choose, this will then be a different type from the `fmapFn` that you're trying to use yourself. So, this definition only compiles with an explicit signature that forces it to be polymorphic <del>(or alternatively, with the `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction` flag, which causes the compiler to pick the polymorphic type without explicit instruction)</del>.

<sup>*EDIT*</sup> Surprisingly it turns out it is *not* the monomorphism restriction what tries to make the type less polymorphic than necessary. To figure out what it is, let's try to find a simpler example with the same problem. First attempt:

```
fromFloat :: RealFrac a => Float -> a
toFloat :: RealFrac a => a -> Float
fromFloat = realToFrac
toFloat   = realToFrac

s = fromFloat . s . toFloat
```

(I chose `Float` because it's not a `default` type that the compiler might pick by itself.)

Turns out this compiles just fine, but instead of the most general type

```
s' :: (RealFrac a, RealFrac b) => a -> b
s' = fromFloat . s' . toFloat
```

it just picks up the simpler

```
s :: Float -> Float
```

...regardless of whether the monomorphism restriction is enabled. *Why?* I don't know; I'd find this an interesting question to ask.

Comment: The program still runs into an infinite type error when you compile with `NoMonomorphismRestriction`, so I don't think what is said about the monomorphism restriction is quite correct.

Comment: Interesting. I made a simpler example that has the same less-general-than-possible behaviour. Would you make this into a question, or shall I?

Comment: You can go ahead and make the question, I think you have a firmer grasp on this than I do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402733/why-does-ghc-infer-a-monomorphic-type-here-even-with-monomorphismrestriction-di

Answer (score 4):

It’s because the f used in the body of the definition of f has a different type than the definition.  This is called polymorphic recursion, and Haskell only allows that if you provide a type signature.
The reason for requiring a type signature is that type inference for polymorphic recursion is undecidable in the general case.

Comment: Yup, same as my answer to the follow-up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402733/why-does-ghc-infer-a-monomorphic-type-here-even-with-monomorphismrestriction-di/55403422#55403422